# Completed sign-up on another device

Tags: bug, sign-up

I posted a question on CS without having created an account. I then started the procedure to sign-up, but finished it by clicking on the link in the email from another device. Problem is, the question is not considered to be asked by me, but by another user with the same name, user which I am on the first device. On this first device, I'm stuck on the "finish signingup" stage. Following the link simply gets me to a sign-up form, and then the system tells me:

> Stack Exchange (foual976@school.lu) belongs to another user (afqt)
>
> You can log in as afqt or cancel to stay logged in as afqt
>
> Log In As afqt cancel

Whatever I click brings me back to the "finish signing up".

What should I do?

Thanks.